# how to json_encode array which contains json string element ? Output should not contains backslash "\"

Tags: php, arrays, json, lumen

For Example

```
$json_string = '{"employee" : { "name" : "test","id" : "1"}}';

    $array = [
                "center"    => "Mumbai",
                "data"      =>  $json_string
    ];

  //echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  //echo json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
  echo json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

It gives following output with backslash in json string:

```
{
 "center": "Mumbai",
 "data": "{\"employee\" : { \"name\" : \"test\",\"id\" : \"1\"}}"
}
```

Even I tried json_encode with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE but same output is comming

Output which I wants to achieve is

```
{
 "center": "Mumbai",
 "data": { "employee" : { "name" : "test","id" : "1"}}
```

}

### **EDIT**

Thank you for your response ,I accepts the both answers and both will definitely work with my question.

---

Editing this question bcoz my requirement is bit different I apologize for this.
Actually I am working with Lumen API and I am fetching records from database, and tables contains one MYsql JSON column and other are normal mysql columns.
for example test_json table has a column with json data type 'employee_details_json'

```
CREATE TABLE `test_json` (
`employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `emplyee_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`employee_details_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
`status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
);
```

Retriving data from this table and sending back as json response is a challenging part here for me. Bcoz Lumen converts whole array to json Lumen json response adding backslash to json column. and this is an example of one table there are many table which contains json columns. Which is why I cant hardcode the column name to decode json before encoding.

Sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
$json_string = '{"employee" : { "name" : "test","id" : "1"}}';
$array = [
     "center"    => "Mumbai",
     "data"      =>  json_decode($json_string)
];
echo json_encode($array);
```

**Output**

```
{"center":"Mumbai","data":{"employee":{"name":"test","id":"1"}}}
```

**UPDATE**
Following is how I would do it in PHP

```php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$response = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_json WHERE employee_id = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // output data of each row
    $a = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row["employee_details_json"] = json_decode($row["employee_details_json"]);
        $response["data"][$a] = $row;
        $a++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();

/*
In Lumen I guess you can achieve this by
I don't know if its the proper way as i never used this framework but you can give it a try
*/
$results = DB::select('SELECT * FROM test_json WHERE employee_id = :employee_id', ['employee_id' => 1]);
$a = 0;
foreach ($results as $row) {

    $results[$a]->employee_details_json = json_decode($row->employee_details_json);
    $a++
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: This is right, $json_string must be decoded first but if its decoded and than encoded again there is no need to use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. It works just using json_encode($array).

Comment: thank you it will work for sure. bt I have bit complex situation. I edited my question request you to have a look

Comment: Okay I need to see the code where you are fetching the data like while loop or whatever you have used.

Answer (score -1):

you can choose from the first solution given from @Ussaid or another method without decoding the string and then encoding it whitch can use more time. Another way to have the desired result is to use stripslashes:

Here is an example with the desired output:

```
$json_string = '{"employee" : { "name" : "test","id" : "1"}}';
$array = [
    "center"    => "Mumbai",
    "data"      =>  $json_string
];
echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
```

Hope it helps and happy codding.

Comment: thank you it will work for sure. bt I have bit complex situation. I edited my question request you to have a look